# How do i get custom post-processing after binding to a backing bean ? Java Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf, binding, seam, customization

What the best way to get custom post-processing after binding to a backing bean, similar to onBind event when using a Spring MVC controller ?

I suppose i need a PhaseListener (after phase Update Model Values) as follows

```
new PhaseListener() {

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {}

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // custom post-processing
    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES;
    }

}
```

Is it a best practice or not ? If not, what should i use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this functionality is there, so you are free to use it.

If you want per-page (per-view actually) phase listener method, use:

```
<f:view afterPhase="#{bean.afterPhase}">
```

If you are using Facelets, the attribute is called `afterPhaseListener`

Answer (score 2):

In a JEE5 server, JSF 1.2 can take advantage of [@PostConstruct](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html):

> JSF implementations running in a Java EE 5 compliant container must support attaching the
>   @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations to aid in awareness of the managedbean
>   lifecycle.
>
> Methods on managed beans declared to be in request, session, or application
>   scope, annotated with @PostConstruct, must be called by the JSF implementation after
>   resource injection is performed (if any) but before the bean is placed into scope.

Comment: Or if jsf-spring integration is used (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hook on the `INVOKE_ACTION` phase? You normally use the bean's action method for this. You can use an `UICommand` component to trigger the event, such as `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton`:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Bean would look like:

```
public String submit() {
    // Do your thing here. The `this.input` is already set.
    return "someNavigationCaseOutcome"; // Can even be null or void for a postback to same page.
}
```

If you just want to cover **all** JSF POST requests, then a `PhaseListener` is indeed the best solution. I would rather hook on the `beforePhase` of the `INVOKE_ACTION` which would make more sense.

Comment: Hi BalusC, You said: why don't you just hook on the INVOKE_ACTION phase ?. Because i use Seam. I have seen your article about JSF life-cycle (+1). Really good.

Comment: I don't do Seam, but I didn't knew that it let the JSF lifecycle behave differently?